# I see only 3 options when I want to see all the email clients on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have multiple email account installed on Android. But when I launch the Intent I see only three of them. I've added also the browsers installed. But still I can see only three options. Is there a way to show all the options available?

[image: Select multiple options]

This is the code I'm using:

```
       fun openEmailPicker(){
            val packageManager = activity.packageManager
            val resInfoEmail = extractResInfoFromIntent("mailto:", packageManager)
            val resInfoBrowser = extractResInfoFromIntent("http://www.gmail.com", packageManager)
            if (resInfoEmail.size > 0) {
                val openInChooser = buildHeader(resInfoEmail, packageManager)
                val emailIntents = createIntentLIst(1, resInfoEmail, packageManager)
                val browserIntents = createIntentLIst(0, resInfoBrowser, packageManager)

                browserIntents.addAll(emailIntents)

                openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, browserIntents.toTypedArray())
                startActivity(openInChooser)
            }
        }

        private fun buildHeader(resInfo: MutableList<ResolveInfo>, packageManager: PackageManager): Intent {
            val resolveInfo = resInfo[0]
            val intentChooser = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)
            return Intent.createChooser(intentChooser, getString(R.string.select_to_open_email))
        }

        private fun createIntentLIst(from: Int, resInfo: MutableList<ResolveInfo>, packageManager: PackageManager): MutableList<LabeledIntent> {
            val intentList: MutableList<LabeledIntent> = ArrayList()
            for (index in from until resInfo.size) {
                extractLabelToLabeledIntent(resInfo, index, packageManager, intentList)
            }
            return intentList
        }

        private fun extractLabelToLabeledIntent(resInfo: MutableList<ResolveInfo>, i: Int, pm: PackageManager, intentList: MutableList<LabeledIntent>) {
            val resolveInfo = resInfo[i]
            val packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
            val intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            intentList.add(LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm), resolveInfo.icon))
        }

        private fun extractResInfoFromIntent(URI: String, packageManager: PackageManager): MutableList<ResolveInfo> {
            val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URI))
            return packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0)
        }
```

Comment: The apps might not support `ACTION_VIEW` with _mailto_. You can analyse the manifests of your email clients to figure which intent filters these support.

Comment: I actually get all the clients if I analyze them with a debugger. But the view only shows the first 3 result. I don't know if it's a limit of the operating system or what

Comment: Have you tried to swipe the bottom sheet up?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Ah yes. It's empty!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what account and what application is. When you fire the `intent`, you get the list of the `applications` that can handle that intent. No matter how many separate `accounts` or whatever are created within these `application`. Once you got an application open, then you can select the account and the address -- you don't get a separate icon for every account within the same application in the intent chooser dialog.

You may get a list of the applications that are capable to handle your `intent` with `queryIntentActivities()` to receive a list of activities.

Official doc for App Chooser: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending

Comment: But I don't want a different icon for every account. I'm just getting outlook and gmail beside chrome but I have more email clients to show. And it only get me 3 of them

Comment: the last line of my code does exactly what you say... am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think those mail clients don't have action intent,

Any way you can add them manually by adding their package names something similar to this

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent shareInent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareInent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareInent, 0);
// put the name of the packages you want in this ArrayList
ArrayList<String> wantedPackage = new ArrayList<>();

if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShare.setType("text/plain");
        String infoPackageName = info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase();

        if (wantedPackage.contains(infoPackageName)) {
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "put your text here");
            targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            resPackageNames.add(infoPackageName);
        }
    }
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Chooser title");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

You can show the email clients in the chooser dialog but I don't think those clients would perform the action you desire since they lack the intent handling.

Comment: I can see them with the debugger, so they have the intent action, I just can't see more than 3 in the picker